# What does Invalid request (Unexpected EOF) for PHP mean?

Tags: php, netbeans-7

I just started with PHP and tested a simple hello world demo and everything runs fine. But about 14 seconds after the code runs I get Invalid request (Unexpected EOF). Why am I getting this when I am not doing anything to invoke it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello All</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="./img/favicon.ico" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo 'Hello';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Netbeans console: [Fri Apr 4 21:51:57 2014] 127.0.0.1:37581 [200]: /index.php [Fri Apr 4 21:52:11 2014] 127.0.0.1:37582 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF) [Fri Apr 4 21:52:11 2014] 127.0.0.1:37583 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

---

Comment: if u do this from a browser, do u still get same error?

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is mentioned on https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60471. From bug description it's somehow related only with Google Chrome.